# rename pandas df index similar to excel drag down

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe with long string indexes.
I want to replace all indexes names with a constant word followed by numbers with ascending order, similiar to excel drag down.
So, my new indexes will be:

ASV1

ASV2

ASV3

ASV4

etc.

Any suggetsions? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a range index, you can try:

```
df.index = 'ASV' + (df.index+1).astype(str)
```

For an arbitrary initial index:

```
df.index = 'ASV' + pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(df)+1)).astype(str)
```